# Pythonic way of percentagechance

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to create a method for having a random chance of an item (represented within a game) such as 20% for one item, or 50% percentage or even 1%. I have tried doing this with the code depicted below:

```
from random import randint

def Break():
    print(".")

def Treasure():

    Gen = randint(1,100)
    if Gen <= 10:
        print("10%")
        Break()

    Gen = randint(1,100)
    if Gen <= 10:
        print("10%")
        Break()

    Gen = randint(1,100)
    if Gen <= 10:
        print("10%")
        Break()

    Gen = randint(1,100)
    if Gen <= 10:
        print("10%")
        Break()

    Gen = randint(1,100)
    if Gen <= 10:
        print("10%")
        Break()
```

This code method kind of works, the problem is that even if a percentage from here is chosen and Break() is called, there is still the possibility of it having more than one percentage listed 
So if It said 80% then Break()
It could also list 50% then Break() a secound time.

**So my question is, how could I do the following:**

- More efficent code
- Make the percentages only call ONE then Break()
- Sure way of making the percentages what they say, eg 50% half chance.

Testing Code: (Edited)

```
if gen <= 10:
    print("10%")
elif gen <= 20:
    print("20%")
elif gen <= 30:
    print("30%")
elif gen <= 40:
    print("30%")
elif gen <= 50:
    print("50%")
elif gen <= 60:
    print("60%")
elif gen <= 70:
    print("70%")
elif gen <= 80:
    print("80%")
elif gen <= 90:
    print("90%")
```

Should this not make 90% the most likely, and in turn 10% the least?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. If you want a random chance why not just use `print(str(randint(1,100)) + '%')`?

Comment: Your `Break` doesn't actually break, use `return` if you want to leave a function early.

Comment: you probably just need one generate and if elif and else statements instead of multiple generate and if statements

Comment: Sorry; Bascially what I want it to do is make an action happen, but say an 80% chance of this happening owuld be greater than a 1% @Holloway

Comment: @Csarg: (responding to edit): no because the tests are cumulative; `if gen <= 80` followed by `elif gen <= 90` makes the second test identical to `elif 80 < gen <= 90` because if `gen <= 80` the second test is never reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things first:

- capitalization matters; `break` and `Break` are two different things
- `break` is a keyword, not a function; call it like `break`, not `break()`
- `break` is to exit a loop, but is not in a loop; maybe you mean `return` instead?

The way you are cascading the cases is throwing your percentages off:

```
gen = randint(1,100)
if gen <= 10:
    return "10% (#1)"

gen = randint(1,100)
if gen <= 10:
    return "10% (#2)"        # 10% of 90% == 9%

gen = randint(1,100)
if gen <= 10:
    return "10% (#3)"        # 10% of 81% == 8.1%
```

For correct values you need to test cumulatively, like

```
gen = randint(1, 100)
if gen <= 10:
    return "10% (#1)"
elif gen <= 20:
    return "10% (#2)"
elif gen <= 30:
    return "10% (#3)"
```

It would probably save a lot of aggravation to wrap this in a class, like

```
from bisect import bisect    # fast binary search
from random import random

class RandomItemGenerator:
    def __init__(self, items=None, probs=None):
        # start with no items
        self.items       = []
        self.total       = 0.
        self.breakpoints = []
        # add any initial items
        if items is not None:
            for item, prob in zip(items, probs):
                self.add_item(item, prob)

    def add_item(self, item, prob):
        self.items.append(item)
        self.total += prob
        self.breakpoints.append(self.total)

    def __call__(self):
        if self.items:
            value = random() * self.total
            index = bisect(self.breakpoints, value)
            return self.items[index]
        else:
            raise ValueError("you haven't got any items yet")
```

then your code looks like

```
make_treasure = RandomItemGenerator()
make_treasure.add_item("sword",    80)
make_treasure.add_item("sword +1", 19)
make_treasure.add_item("ring +2",   1)
```

which we can test like

```
from collections import Counter

# generate 10,000 items
test = Counter(make_treasure() for i in range(10000))

# check number of each item generated
print(test.most_common())
```

which gives something like

```
[('sword', 8002), ('sword +1', 1887), ('ring +2', 111)]
```

---

**Edit**: an example returning functions:

```
def sword_fn():
    # your stuff goes here

def dagger_fn():
    # your stuff goes here

def wand_fn():
    # your stuff goes here

make_fn = RandomItemGenerator()
make_fn.add_item(sword_fn,  80)
make_fn.add_item(dagger_fn, 19)
make_fn.add_item(wand_fn,    1)

which = make_fn()      # pick a function
which()                # run the function
```

My last comment used an equivalent shorthand, like

```
make_fn = RandomItemGenerator([sword_fn, dagger_fn, wand_fn], [80, 19, 1])
```

which does exactly the same thing as the four lines above, where I create the instance and then add items.

Comment: I edited my code, could you see if the percentages will work?

Comment: Does make_treasure.add_item("ring +2",   1) mean the '1' is the chance? and the +2 the amount?

Comment: Also, how would I make it execute a function when one of the treasures is created?

Comment: The +1 and +2 are just part of the descriptive text; 80, 19, and 1 are the relative probability of each being returned. I chose those values so they sum to 100, making them percentages, but the class is written so that it doesn't matter (any final sum will work).

Comment: You can add functions as items instead of strings, then call the function which is returned; something like `pick_fn = RandomItemGenerator([fn1, fn2, fn3], [80, 19, 1])` then `pick_fn()()` (the first pair of parentheses gets a function, the second pair runs it).

Comment: Could you edit your code? Don't quite understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that :

```
def Break():
    print(".")

def FindAnotherName():
    Gen = randint(1,100)
    if Gen <= 10:
        print("10%")
        Break()
        return True
    else:
        return False

def Treasure():

    i = 0
    finished = False
    while (i < 5 && finished == False):
        finished = FinAnotherName()
        i = i + 1
```